# Small, "bouncy" lags when pushing an SKShapeNode with another shape moved by an SKAction

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction, skshapenode

I am creating a 2D autoscroller and when my player (with a circle `physicsBody`) collides with an SKAction `moveTo`-powered obstacle which is moving towards it, it makes small, almost unnoticable lags. I tried lowering the friction and the density of the objects, but nothing helped. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you define lag?  is the entire game slowing down and FPS dropping,  or is your character just getting stuck when hitting  an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have chosen to use a circle with phycsicsBody. An `SKPhysicsBody` object is used to add physics simulation to a node. When a scene processes a new frame, it performs physics calculations on physics bodies attached to nodes in the scene. These calculations include gravity, friction, and collisions with other bodies. After the scene completes these calculations, it updates the positions and orientations of the node objects.

You have also chosen to use `SKActions`, when using the actions to move a body such changes don't go through the physics engine, indeed usually you could add unwanted actions and unexpected events as "bouncy lags".

So, if you're using physics to move a body, you shouldn't use move actions, apply an impulse or force, or set it's velocity directly

Answer (score 0):

Setting restitution to zero may help. This controls the elasticity, or bounciness of a sprite.